# Whаt is happening here?

Tags: java, string, logical-operators

Rules for valid Indian mobile number:

The number should contain 10 or 11 or 12 digits.

If it contains 10 digits, then the first digit should be 7 or 8 or 9.

If it contains 11 digits, then the first digit should be 0 and the second rule followed.

If it contains 12 digits, then the first two digits should be 91 and the second rule followed.

For test case:

```
1
881906355596
```

this code should produce Invalid but it is showing Valid.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG
 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int t=scan.nextInt();
     while((t--)!=0){

         String s = scan.next();
         int length = s.length();

         if((length==10) &&((s.charAt(0)=='7')||(s.charAt(0)=='9')||(s.charAt(0)=='8')))
         System.out.println("Valid");

         else if((length==11) &&(s.charAt(0)=='0')&&(s.charAt(0)=='7')||(s.charAt(0)=='9')||(s.charAt(0)=='8'))
         System.out.println("Valid");//code

         else if((length==12) &&(s.charAt(0)=='9')&&(s.charAt(1)=='1'))
         System.out.println("Valid");//code

         else System.out.println("Invalid");
     }
     }
}
```

Comment: Use `regex` to validate mobile numbers.

Comment: yes i can use it but i want to know what is happening here. @MushifAliNawaz

Comment: why are you looping?

Comment: for multiple testcases @ScaryWombat

Comment: `(s.charAt(0)=='0')&&(s.charAt(0)=='7')` can this condition evaluate to `true`?

Comment: Can `881906355596` be processed as an `int`?

Comment: In the first `else if` `s.charAt(0)=='8'` is true.

Comment: "If it contains 11 digits, then the first digit should be 0 and the second rule followed." - doesn't this mean that the _first_ character should be 0 and the _second_ should be either 7, 8 or 9? That would mean `(s.charAt(0)=='0')&&(s.charAt(0)=='7')||...` should be `(s.charAt(0)=='0')&&((s.charAt(1)=='7' )||...)` (check the chars at index 1 for 7, 8 or 9 - and note that I added parentheses to the "or"-sequence)

Comment: @Guy but length is not 10 then it should be false

Comment: @RituRajShrivastava You have `or` there, it evaluates to `length == 11 || s.charAt(0) == '8'`, which it true,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second and third conditions are wrong.

The second condition incorrectly returns `true` for your `881906355596` input.

You'll see why if you arrange it as follows:

```
else if (
    (length==11) &&           // false &&
    (s.charAt(0)=='0') &&     // false &&
    (s.charAt(0)=='7') ||     // false ||
    (s.charAt(0)=='9') ||     // false || 
    (s.charAt(0)=='8')        // true 
)                             // equals true
```

It should be:

```
else if (length == 11 && s.charAt(0) == '0' && (s.charAt(1) == '7' || s.charAt(1) == '9' || s.charAt(1) == '8'))
```

The third condition should be:

```
else if (length == 12 && s.charAt(0) == '9' && s.charAt(1) == '1' && (s.charAt(2) == '7' || s.charAt(2) == '9' || s.charAt(2) == '8'))
```

Answer (score -3):

You missed one whole `()`

```java
else if((length==12) &&((s.charAt(0)=='9')&&(s.charAt(1)=='1')))
```

Comment: It doesn't meter when using `&&`. All the brackets except the `if`'s are redundant.